# Draw an antialias ellipse region for label

Tags: c#, winforms, label, drawing

I drew an ellipse-like region for a label but i don't know how to set the antialias for it.

Snippet:

```
Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(0, 0, labelVoto.Width,labelVoto.Height);
var path = new GraphicsPath();
path.AddEllipse(circle);
labelVoto.Region = new Region(path);
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Regions do not support anti-aliasing.  Just keep in mind that Label is an incredibly expensive way to avoid adding code to its parent's Paint event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SmoothingMode` of the `Graphics` object. Override `OnPaintBackground` instead of changing the `Region`. Regions do not support anti-aliasing. This example creates a customized label by deriving it from `Label`.

```
public class EllipticLabel : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // This ensures that the corners of the label will have the same color as the
        // container control or form. They would be black otherwise.
        e.Graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);

        // This does the trick
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        var rect = ClientRectangle;
        rect.Width--;
        rect.Height--;
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor)) {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

If you set the paint rectangle size equal to `ClientRectangle`. The ellipse will be clipped by one pixel to the right and at the bottom. Therefore I reduce its size by one pixel.

You set the desired background color of the ellipse by setting the `BackColor` property of the label in code or in the properties window.

Result:

[image]

Once you have compiled the code, the customized label automatically appears in the `Toolbox` in the current project.

Comment: But he asks about Regions