# Why does my circular panel control look blurry?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code

```
class CircularPanel : Panel
    {
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsPath g = new GraphicsPath();
            g.AddEllipse(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(g);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
```

When I create this class, rebuild my project and then drag it onto the form it looks blurry and the corners are flattened, how can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Because Region doesn't support antialiasing.

Comment: I don't know what that is but is there any way I can make my code work?

Comment: No way, I'm afraid. Antialiasing is the technique to create smothness on a raster image by adding pixels that are either semitransparent of a mix of background and foreground colors. Winforms is not good at such things.

Comment: See [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035114/5734097), it is without Region thou...